# Use Azure DevOps Personal access token to call Azure DevOps Services REST API via Azure Data Factory

Tags: authentication, azure-data-factory, azure-devops-rest-api, personal-access-token

I have an Azure DevOps Personal access token with read access. I need to call Azure DevOps Services REST APIs via Azure Data Factory's Web Activity. The API documentation is available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

 I dont have a ClientID or Client Secret but, as mentioned earlier, a personal access token. How do I authenticate using the same? 
Would really appreciate any ideas here?

Best regards,
Sree

Comment: Any ideas anyone??

Answer (score 2):

It might be too late to answer your question, but I just did exactly what you asked for.

In my case, I'm calling a DevOps API to run one of my pipelines.

- In the URL field of my Web activity I have: [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipeline](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/pipelines/%7Bpipeline) number}/runs?api-version=7.1-preview.1
- The Authentication is set to 'None'
- In the headers, I added a field 'Authorization' with the value 'Basic xxxx' where 'xxxx' is my personnal access token

See a screenshot here:
[Web activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGaMA.png)